# Posso usar MIT junto com GPL?

Tags: licença, gpl

Existem diversas licenças de software pelo mundo, mas me deparei com um problema que pode as vezes até chegar ao nível *legal*. E isso não seria muito bom para o meu projeto.

Meu software esta licenciado sob a licença MIT, até aí tudo bem, mas eu gostaria de incluir trechos (ou partes inteiras) de software que estão sob a licença GPL.

Segundo a licença GPL:

> *You are allowed to sell copies of the modified program commercially, but only under the terms of the GNU GPL. Thus, for instance, you must make the source code available to the users of the program as described in the GPL, and they must be allowed to redistribute and modify it as described in the GPL.*
>
> *These requirements are the condition for including the GPL-covered code you received in a program of your own.*

O trecho diz que eu preciso incluir o código para os usuários, o que eu já faço, junto com a licença MIT.

Mas parte desse código esta sob a licença GPL, onde eu deveria dizer que tal trecho esta sob GP` e que não é originalmente meu? Eu posso fazer isso?

**P.S**: Se possível um exemplo prático e simples.

**P.S 2**: Isso vale para *package manager* também, eu posso incluir um arquivo GPL através de `packages.json`? (composer, npm, etc)

Comment: Essa **[resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902754/mit-vs-gpl-license)** do SOen pode ajudar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou usando classes licensiadas sob GPL, que estão sendo incluidas junto ao repositorio para facilitar a vida.

Comment: Sim eu entendo isto Olimon, o que eu quero dizer é que algumas classes você pode escrever sob uma licença e outras classes sob outra licença e o software completo que usa destas classes (por exemplo classe Helper, Connection, WebService, etc) pode ser escrito em uma outra licença ainda. Desculpe se não me fiz claro inicialmente, espero que ajude.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento esse ultimo comentario ficou e deixou tudo mais claro, obrigado mesmo :)

Comment: Uma coisa, eu não sei que tipo de software e ou linguagem você está usando, mas eu constumo em `C/C++` escrever as classes em arquivos separados, por exemplo `helper.c` e `helper.h` são escritos sob a licença MIT e ficam em uma pasta chamada por exemplo "include", já o arquivos que são escritos sob a licença proprietária (geralmente são código que fazem as regras da empresa) eu constumo colocar em uma pasta chamada "model", em outras palavras, procure evitar de misturar códigos de licenças diferentes em um mesmo arquivo :) Boa sorte Olimon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A licença MIT é compatível com a licença GPL, de modo que não há empecilho em se ter um sistema com alguns componentes sob uma dessas licenças e outros sob a outra. A questão é qual a forma correta de se licenciar *o produto final*, e de fato somente um advogado poderá te dizer isso.

De acordo com *a interpretação da FSF*, se `A` está sob a GPL e `B` está sob a MIT, `A+B` está sob a GPL. Isso não é necessariamente a mesma interpretação que *a justiça* daria, que isso fique bem claro. De todo modo, os componentes que você desenvolveu - da qual você é autor e detém os direitos - ainda podem ser distribuídos livremente sob qualquer licença compatível com a GPL.

Ou seja, se alguém pegar `A+B`, jogar `A` fora e quiser incorporar `B` em um projeto proprietário, por exemplo, ele pode - pois `B` está sob a MIT, conforme sua própria decisão. Entretanto, se alguém quiser incorporar `A+B` em um projeto proprietário, ele não pode, pois o componente `A` - do qual você *não é* autor e portanto *não detém* os direitos - ainda está sob a GPL, que não permite isso.

Note também que as restrições impostas pela GPL referem-se somente à **redistribuição**: se você nunca distribuir `A+B` pra ninguém - instalar num servidor e oferecer como serviço, por exemplo - então pouco importa em que licença está `B` (aliás, `B` pode não estar sob *nenhuma* licença, pois você não o está redistribuindo...), você não viola a GPL simplesmente por **usar** nem **modificar** o componente `A`.

Em resumo, se você quer evitar problemas, licencie seu produto final como GPL, e apenas *os componentes específicos de sua autoria* como MIT. Se essas condições não lhe forem satisfatórias, procure ajuda especializada.

Comment: A licença GPL não é viral? digo se um software tem algum componente sob a GPL todo o resto deve ser GPL?

Comment: @Ricardo Não exatamente, veja a parte que eu escrevi que "se A está sob a GPL e B está sob a MIT, A+B está sob a GPL". Ela é viral porque o conjunto tem que respeitar a GPL, mas as partes individuais (se auto-contidas) podem estar em qualquer licença compatível com a GPL.

Answer (score 8):

Só um advogado especializado pode te orientar corretamente. Posso te dar uma informação preliminar.

Se você descreveu sua situação corretamente (é impressionante como é comum a pessoa não entender sua própria situação) me parece que não há problema em incluir código GPL em um projeto MIT desde que os fontes que usam GPL contenham claramente a informação de que aquele código está sob licença GPL. Precisa ficar claro que aquele trecho tem mais restrições que o resto do código e que ele não poderá ser usado da mesma forma.

Você deve obrigatoriamente incluir as informações de autoria, de direito de cópia e o texto da licença GPL. Isto deve estar em todos os arquivos fonte. Evidentemente que o texto completo da licença pode ser referenciado para um arquivo contido no repositório.

Uma sugestão é entrar em contato com o mantenedor do projeto GPL e perguntar se o que está fazendo está ok para ele. Um advogado vai exigir que isto seja por escrito e que seja de alguém que comprovadamente tem autoridade para assinar aquilo. O que é bem difícil conseguir.

Este é o meu entendimento da licença mas pode não ser o de todo mundo. Já vi muita discussão por isto. Este é o problema de perguntar sobre questões legais em um *site* de desenvolvimento.

Então o ideal é deixar bem separada a parte que é GPL, até para facilitar quem queira substituir esta parte. De preferência em outro repositório. Se isto não for possível, você pode ter problemas (embora eu nunca vi um processo por violação de licença GPL).

Só tenha em mente que você não pode mudar a licença do código GPL e não pode deixar nenhuma porta aberta para quem use seu código seja confundido por sua causa e acabe usando indevidamente a parte GPL.

Olhando por outro lado se seu projeto é difícil dissociar as partes GPL e MIT, na prática você tem um projeto GPL. Afinal ninguém poderá usar uma parte do projeto de uma forma e outra parte de outra. GPL é viral, ou seja, ela contamina tudo que está próximo dela.

Particularmente eu não colocaria código GPL em um projeto que eu desejo que seja MIT. Eu poderia usar algo GPL para fazer algum componente opcional ou que pode ser completamente separado da parte MIT. Assim eu garanto que a parte MIT possa ser usada como MIT mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).